# Internet Explorer Displaying Borders Incorrectly?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border

Internet Explorer 7 and below is not displaying my Borders and if so, it is not displaying them correctly?

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/nue/

Any ideas? There should be a border placed at the bottom of the whole HEADER TAG and one above the FOOTER TAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take off the `border-top-color` rule (on the header) and `border-top-color` on the footer; that appears to fix the issue. It may be that the color is not dark enough; you could try a darker color (I can barely see it on IE7 on the bottom). You can use a conditional comment or the hack `*bottom-border-color: none` to target IE7 and below.

Comment: What do you mean by applying border-top-color to the HEADER and FOOTER TAGs, I only have BORDER-TOP applied to the FOOTER and BORDER-BOTTOM to the HEADER. Thank you :)

Comment: In IE, hit F12 to see the developer tools. If you inspect those two tags, you will see IE is applying the border color you specified. However, it seems to blend in too much with the background, making it seem like the border isn't working (it is, I can see it). My suggestion is to either change the color or use `none` for the color (defaults to black, then). I should mention I am using IE9 in IE7 render mode to view your site.

Comment: But I still want there to be like a transparency effect. Which is why there are blending in per se... It's a DASHED border. Not a solid, eh?

Comment: Right, it is dashed but the dash color is blending in it seems in IE, so it appears solid (the header). I can *kind of* see the dash in the footer, but making it `#000` makes it stand out more. So you could do a lighter color or darker. Make sense?